# Why I get ID = 0 when new row inserted to the table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use Entity frameWork to save new row to my database.

I created method that insert new object to the table.The object is added to the table but method returns me always 0 .While I expect the new `Id`.

Here is the method:

```
private int SaveVectorLayer(VVectorLayer layer)
{
    if (layer == null) return 0;

    Data.VectorLayer vectorLayer;
    if (layer.Id == 0)
    {
        vectorLayer = new Data.VectorLayer();
        _context.Entry(vectorLayer).State = EntityState.Added;
    }
    else
    {
        vectorLayer = _context.VectorLayers.Find(layer.Id);
        if (vectorLayer == null) throw new ObjectNotFoundException(string.Format("Layer with id={0} not found!", layer.Id));
    }
    vectorLayer.Title = layer.Title;
    if (layer.Style != null) layer.Style.SaveStyle(vectorLayer);
    vectorLayer.MinScale = layer.MinScale;
    vectorLayer.MaxScale = layer.MaxScale;
    vectorLayer.GeomType = layer.GeomType ?? "Point";

    _context.SaveChanges();

    return layer.Id;
}
```

Any idea why returned Id is always 0?

Comment: Because you didn't set a value and it's not IDENTITY ? Or because you are looking at the wrong class? You are saving `vectorLayer`, not `layer`

Comment: if you always get 0 it's because this is always true.. if (layer == null) return 0;..

Answer (score 3):

Your return statement should be `vectorLayer.Id`. 
You are currently returning the `Id` of the object that was not found in the database and had an `Id` of 0.

In addition regarding the following code:

```
vectorLayer.Title = layer.Title;
if (layer.Style != null) layer.Style.SaveStyle(vectorLayer);
vectorLayer.MinScale = layer.MinScale;
vectorLayer.MaxScale = layer.MaxScale;
vectorLayer.GeomType = layer.GeomType ?? "Point";
```

Consider encapsulating it using a clone like method or a `Copy Constructor`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return `vectorLayer.Id`.  You never actually set the `layer.Id` anywhere.  `vectorLayer` is what you create and add to the DB.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with this code.

1. As everyone else noticed, you are saving `vectorLayer`, not `layer`. If you want to return an ID, you should return `vectorLayer.Id`
2. Your code returns `0` if the input is missing :

   ```
   if (layer == null) return 0;
   ```

   That's not a good idea. It means that you can't differentiate between actual 0s and invalid input. If this is unexpected, throw an exception. If it is, change the method to `bool TrySaveVectorLayer(layer,out int id)`, or (bool ok,int id) SaveVectorLayer(layer)`.

Worst case, return a **negative** number or some value that's clearly invalid, so you know at least what happened.

It could be something else entirely though, like an ID field that isn't autogenerated, eg through an `IDENTITY()` or SEQUENCE

Answer (score 0):

```
return layer.Id; //this id is of wrong object
```

The above line is returning the ID of the **VVectorLayer**. But you actually want to return the `ID` of the inserted data row. That will be the Id in the entity `vectorLayer`.

So you have to return `vectorLayer.Id;`